# How to make ExtTextOut render correctly for Vietnamese character

Tags: c#, character-encoding

My C# program takes text input from the user and creates a web request to Wikipedia for suggestions, and then outputs the suggestions to an owner-drawn `ListView` using the Win32 API function `ExtTextOut` function.

Some suggestions come back encoded, like this:

```
Abridged Chronicles of \\u0110\\u1ea1i Vi\\u1ec7t
```

so I decoded them using `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape`

to produce this:

```
Abridged Chronicles of Đại Việt
```

Although the above string with its literal Vietnamese characters renders fine in a `TextBox`, `RichTextBox` and anywhere in Visual Studio's debugger, it does not render correctly when sent through `ExtTextOut`.

Here is how it looks:

[image]

I tried changing my `DllImport` statement for `ExtTextOut` to use the W version:

```
[DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "ExtTextOutW")]
public static extern int ExtTextOut(IntPtr hdc, int x, int y, int options,
    ref RECT clip, String str, int len, IntPtr spacings);
```

but that just rendered Asian characters for all output.

I looked into the Language options on my Windows computer but that doesn't seem to be the right place to correct the problem because `RichTextBox` can render the characters just fine (so can Visual Studio and my web browser while browsing Wikipedia, for that matter).

I tried to convert the string, like this:

```
byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
byte[] unicodeBytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Unicode, utf8Bytes);
str = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(unicodeBytes);
```

but that did not do anything and I am not surprised, given that (correct me if I'm wrong) in .NET, a string in memory is always encoded with UTF-16, so the code above really did nothing.

How is it possible to use `ExtTextOut` to show the characters correctly or do I need a different approach?

Comment: What's the point of using `ExtTextOut()`? You can use `Graphics.DrawString()` or `TextRenderer` in .NET to do the same thing. If you want help with code that doesn't work, you need to provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces your problem.

Comment: Is it me or do members of this site sometimes respond with more criticism then necessary, despite one's best efforts? I thought I provided enough to go on but I didn't know about that page so thank you for that. I will amend the question and make them better in the future. For the choice of functions, I wrote the text-rendering code many years ago and I believe there was a problem with `Graphics.DrawString()` and with `TextRenderer` but I will revisit and see.

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like the solution was to add `Charset = Charset.Unicode`:

```
[DllImport("gdi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint = "ExtTextOutW")]
public static extern int ExtTextOut(IntPtr hdc, int x, int y, int options, ref RECT clip,
    String str, int len, IntPtr spacings);
```